# Java-Spring: Как выдавать JSON со связями?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Всем доброго дня!
Сервер написан на `Java + Spring framework + Postgresql`. Мне нужно выдавать `JSON` такого вида:

```
Категория1:
    id
    name
     Подкатегория1
        id
        name
         Товар1
           id
           name
Категория2:
    id
    name
     Подкатегория1
        id
        name
         Товар1
           id
           name
```

Но сейчас у меня реализовано так:

```
Товар1
   id
   name
```

Мой код:
**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class ReminderController {

    @Autowired
    private BasicService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dishes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Dish> getAllDishes() {
        return service.getAllDishes();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Categories> getAllCategories() {
        return service.getAllCategories();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/menu", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Menu> getAllMenu() {
        return service.getAllMenu();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/reminders/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Dish getReminder(@PathVariable("id") long remindId) {
        return service.getById(remindId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/reminders", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Dish saveReminder(@RequestBody Dish dish) {
        return service.save(dish);
    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/reminders{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        service.remove(id);
    }
}
```

**Сущности:
Categories.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")

public class Categories {

    private List<Dish> dish;
    private Menu menu;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "menu_id", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int menuId;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return dish;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "menuId")
    public Menu getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getMenuId() {
        return menuId;
    }

    public void setMenuId(int menuId) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Categories() {

    }
}
```

**Dish.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish")

public class Dish {

    private Categories categories;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "description_ru", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionRu;

    @Column(name = "description_eng", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionEng;

    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imgUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dishCategoryId")
    public Categories getDishCategory() {
        return categories;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public String getDescriptionRu() {
        return descriptionRu;
    }

    public void setDescriptionRu(String descriptionRu) {
        this.descriptionRu = descriptionRu;
    }

    public String getDescriptionEng() {
        return descriptionEng;
    }

    public void setDescriptionEng(String descriptionEng) {
        this.descriptionEng = descriptionEng;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Dish() {

    }

}
```

**Menu.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    private List<Categories> category;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "menu")
    public List<Categories> getCategories() {
        return category;
    }

    public Menu() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**BasicService.java**

```
public interface BasicService {

    List<Dish> getAllDishes();
    List<Categories> getAllCategories();
    List<Menu> getAllMenu();
    Dish getById(long id);
    Dish save(Dish dish);
    void remove(long id);

}
```

**BasicServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class BasicServiceImpl implements BasicService {

    @Autowired
    private DishesRepository dishesRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CategoriesRepository categoriesRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MenuRepository menuRepository;

    public List<Dish> getAllDishes() {
        return dishesRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Categories> getAllCategories() {
        return categoriesRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Menu> getAllMenu() {
        return menuRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Dish getById(long id) {
        return dishesRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public Dish save(Dish dish) {
        return dishesRepository.saveAndFlush(dish);
    }

    public void remove(long id) {
        dishesRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Лош ошибки:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reminderController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicService com.qoobico.remindme.server.controller.ReminderController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicService com.qoobico.remindme.server.controller.ReminderController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e2ce3b5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
```

Как мне реализовать это легче всего? Потому что знаний в спринге очень мало. Мне главное выдавать JSON чтобы я мог их обрабатывать на клиенте в андроид.

Comment: А у вас `Category` с `Dish` точно один к одном ? У вас получается, что стоит связь один-к-одному, но при этому у категории много блюд и у блюд много категорий.

Comment: вроде как да, вот это я добавил в Dish -     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dishCategoryId")
    public Categories getDishCategory() {
        return categories;
    }

Comment: А какой результат по запросу на `url` `categories` ?

Comment: у меня war'ник даже не деплоится, выходит злая ошибка (лог ошибки я залил в вопрос)

Comment: лог ошибки залил в вопрос, он слишком длинным оказался

Comment: А репозитории у вас имеют аннотацию `@Repository` ? Приложите их к задаче.

Comment: вы про интерфейс? если да, то вот мои 3 интерфейса:

Comment: public interface MenuRepository extends JpaRepository<Menu, Long> {
}

Comment: public interface CategoriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Categories, Long> {
}

Comment: public interface DishesRepository extends JpaRepository<Dish, Long>{
}

Comment: аннотации @Repository нет